# Python: Can't fetch data from API

Tags: python

This is all my code. It's giving me a 403 forbidden error, even though if I type the same URL into google, I get the data.

```
import urllib.request, json

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1') as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Just use beautifulsoup library to fetch the API data from the link.

Comment: I want to get the data from that url and print the object to the console.

Comment: use beautiful soup library to fetch the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I use the requests module, it works

```
import requests  
response = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
for i in response: print(i)
```

Comment: @ZeroSevenTen The `requests` module is a third party library, but it has become the standard (and best) way to make requests in Python. If you are able to install it in your environment, I would go with this answer.